# expected primary-expression before '...' token calling templated method of templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a templated static method in a templated class, and I'm calling it from a templated function. Compilation fails with the error `error: expected primary-expression before '...' token`.

Here's a sample code. It has some unused template parameters, but fails exectly the same as my real code, where these parameters are important.

```
temp late<typename T>
class Run {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    static void run(Args... args) {}
};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void
run2(Args ...args)
{
    Run<int>::run<Args...>(args...);   // OK
    Run<T>::run<Args...>(args...);     // Fail on first . in Args...
}

int main() {
    run2<int>(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
%  g++ -std=gnu++11 -o try try.cc
try.cc: In function 'void run2(Args ...)':
try.cc:13:21: error: expected primary-expression before '...' token
     Run<T>::run<Args...>(args...);     // Fail on first . in Args...
                     ^
try.cc:13:21: error: expected ';' before '...' token
```

Used gcc 4.8.5 on Ubuntu. Also reproduces with gcc 6.3

Any idea what's going on? The difference between the working line (with `<int`>) and the failing line (with `<T>`) is particularly confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
Run<T>::template run<Args...>(args...);
```

`Run<int>` is non dependent template whereas `Run<T>` is.

BTW, in your example, you don't even need to specify arguments, and just let deduction occur:

```
Run<int>::run(args...);
Run<T>::run(args...);
```

Comment: Works great. I can't rely on deduction in my real code, because of trouble with references (I construct function types which must match exactly, long story).